# How do I query using JPA to get list of entities which do not contain a FK entity as its member?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have a `Promotion` which contains a list of `PromotionDetails`.
`PromotionDetails` is a information of promotion for each products.
How do I get a list of promotion which do not contain a certain product?

For example

```
promotion_id  |     name
===========================
       1      |  'Promo A'
       2      |  'Promo B'

promotion_id  | product_id
===========================
       1      |      1
       1      |      2
       1      |      3
       1      |      4
       2      |      1
       2      |      3
       2      |      4
       2      |      5

  product_id  | name
===========================
       1      | 'Product A'
       2      | 'Product B'
       3      | 'Product C'
       4      | 'Product D'
       5      | 'Product E'
       6      | 'Product F'
```

doing `PromotionRepository#findAllPromotionWithNoProductId(1)` should return empty array

doing `PromotionRepository#findAllPromotionWithNoProductId(2)` should return second promotion

doing `PromotionRepository#findAllPromotionWithNoProductId(6)` should return all promotion

Below is my code:

```
@Entity
public class Promotion {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "promotion_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "promotion")
    private List<PromotionDetails> details = new ArrayList<>();

    //more code
}

@Entity
@IdClass(PromotionPK.class)
public class PromotionDetails  {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "promotion_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "promotion_id")
    private Promotion promotion;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", 
                referencedColumnName = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    //more code

}

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String name;

    //more code
}

@Repository
public interface PromotionRepository extends JpaRepository<Promotion, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT p "
            + "FROM Promotion p "
            + "INNER JOIN promotion.details d "
            + "WHERE p.id = d.promotion.id "
            + "AND d.product.id <> :productId ")   
    List<Promotion> findAllPromotionWithNoProductId(@Param("productId") Long productId);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
public List<Promotion> findByProductIdNotIn(long id);
```

**EDIT :** Check [section 2.3.2](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html), Table 2.3